# Unauthenticated user access to a URL with location element is not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-authentication, asp.net-authorization

I am using ASP.NET forms authentication for my web app. I have a folder to which I would like to grant access to unauthenticated users. I am using IIS 7 and the app pool is in the integrated mode. As a test, I created hello.txt inside ScriptsHandlers folder. When I try to browse it using IIS, I get redirected to the login page despite the location element. Also, when I am running my application, I get 401 Unauthorized errors when querying asmx web services stored in the folder.
Here is a snippet of my web.config:

```
<location path="ScriptsHandlers">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location allowOverride="true">
    <system.web>
      <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="Views/Login.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" cookieless="UseUri" slidingExpiration="true" />
      </authentication>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Comment: Try swapping the order of the two `location` elements, so that the element for the root directory comes before the element for the sub-directory.

Answer (score 0):

Allow access to everything inside ScriptsHandlers folder

```
ScriptsHandlers Or /ScriptsHandler depending on where you keep this web.config
<location path="ScriptsHandlers">
   <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```